# http://localhost/ not working with EasyPHP

Tags: localhost, easyphp

I've verified my host file in `windows/system32/drivers/etc/` has an entry for localhost in it, but it's not going anywhere.  I have to have a port number in the URL: http://127.0.0.1:8888/

Is there anything I can do to get `localhost` working without the need for a port number?

Comment: does http://localhost:8888/ work?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your EasyPHP is probably configured to listen on port 8888.

You must configure EasyPHP to listen on port 80 as well.

For your information, the default port for HTTP is the port 80, so when you don't give any port information in the url, your browser is trying to connect on port 80.

You can follow this tutorial : http://technology.ohmygoh.com/easyphp-how-to-change-apache-server-port/

Comment: http://technology.iamthebossofmylife.com/easyphp-how-to-change-apache-server-port/

Answer (score 14):

For windows 8 users, you should also make sure that you are running it as administrator.

Right click on easyPHP shortcut and change the compatibility setting to always run as administrator.

After this, make sure the "httpd.conf" file in "C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-12.1\conf_files"

Has this line in it:

Listen 127.0.0.1:80

To verify that you had my problem, check 127.0.0.1:8887/

Answer (score 1):

Try editing conf_files/httpd.conf.

Change values listed as 8888 to 80, and you should not need to use a port on restart.

Answer (score 1):

Find in httpd.conf below... 
Options FollowSymLinks Indexes 
AllowOverride None 
Order deny,allow 
Allow from 127.0.0.1

And add line like this: 
Allow from ::1

Result: 
Options FollowSymLinks Indexes 
AllowOverride None 
Order deny,allow 
Allow from 127.0.0.1 
Allow from ::1

And restart apache..:)

Answer (score 1):

Following these steps may solve your problem:

- from EasyPHP icon right click -> properties
- select "Compatibility" tab
- check "Run this program in compatibility mode for:" and select Windows 7

Answer (score 0):

You can try to run your webserver on Port 80.

Answer (score 0):

for an http url the default port 80. ie http://localhost is equal to http://localhost:80 which is also equals to the ip-http://127.0.0.1

like Krtek said you can refer the tutorial in a reverse way.

Answer (score 0):

default port is 8887
press F7 function key to open in browser

Answer (score 0):

I had the same trouble today and when I tried to fix this by changing the port by the EasyPHP program, this didn't resolve. If this occurs try go to folder `program/apache/conf` and manually change `httpd.conf`:

Here the `httpd` of the program folder indicates `127.0.0.1:80` while httpd conf apache folder show `127.0.0.1:8887`.