# Error 404 when using IP for lan site on EasyPHP

Tags: apache, easyphp, devserver

Basically i've been using EasyPHP for setting up an website for work, everything works fine except that i can't access my website from another computer, not even from my own if using my own IP.
If i use either localhost or 127.0.0.1 i can access my site just fine, but using my ip 192.168.25.65 will return an 404 error. Trying to access it in another machine using my IP will also return the 404 error.

I've been trying several solutions. Most of the make it so my http server won't start. Currently my configs are

```
Listen *:80

<VirtualHost 192.168.25.65>
    DocumentRoot "C:/EasyPHP-Devserver-17/eds-www"
    ServerName 192.168.25.65
    <Directory "C:/EasyPHP-Devserver-17/eds-www">
        Options FollowSymLinks Indexes ExecCGI
        AllowOverride All
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
        #Deny from all
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I've tryed changing the ips on virtual host to * instead of my own but it made it so that the Http server wouldn't start. I can't find any other solutions on google since all other people seem to have issues with firewall blocking which returns the connection refused error, mine just tells me that there isn't anthing at my IP, even tho there is.
 I'm looking for a solution for this problem, being it in the http.conf file or anything else, if I forgot to mention any information that you think is needed please inform me and i'll include it.

Comment: does `http://192.168.25.65:80` or simply `http://192.168.25.65` work?

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss no, as i said only localhost and 127.0.0.1 work, trying http://192.168.25.65 and http://192.168.25.65:80 on my machine will simply return 404

Comment: Does anything here help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5194810/http-localhost-not-working-with-easyphp  i.e. check your http://192.168.25.65:8888 also.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss nope , it also doesn't work. Also tryed compatibility mode which was also sugested in that question. Didn't work either, same 404 error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I figured it out with some toying around, turns out even if I change the port on http.conf apache just changes it back to :80# for some reason, so it doesn't matter what I do it will try to listen on that port. So i checked who was using that port and the one at fault was Skype. I just changed Skype port to a random one now(Which was easy since it doesn't change itself back to the one it was using like some other ones do... I'm looking at you Apache) they're both working properly, i assume the 404 error was due to the fact that when i used my own Ip instead of going for the easyphp page it sent me to whatever the skype page is, which is blank.